# How to add google analytics tracking id to Communities built on Salesforce Tabs+ Visualforce

Tags: community, google-analytics

Google Tracking Id can be set for communities through Community Builder (advanced setting) however for communities that are on the 'Salesforce Tabs+ Visualforce' template community builder is not available.

How to set google analytics tracking no in this scenario. I guess it will need to be set directly through javascript into the visualforce page or is there any other better way.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_analytics_tracking_code.htm&type=0) has the details you are looking for

[image]

Also If you want to include it on multiple pages create a template out of it and include it in multiple pages.

Comment: The community i am in is using "Salesforce Tabs+ Visualforce" template , there is no way that I can find in config to set the Trackin ID ie: setting the UA-XXXX no: As per documentation this can be set through the Coummunity Builder. But if the template used is "Salesforce Tabs+ Visualforce" , community builder is not visible so this cannot be set this way,  unless I am missing something. Once tracking id is set , it can be used in VF through the component <site:googleAnalyticsTracking>.

Comment: Please read the first 3 steps from the instructions i pasted. Its showing the exact way to work around it.

Comment: Thanks for investigating.  The field 'Analytics Tracking Code'  is available for site but not community. For communities its through  community builder  i guess this will need to be applied through custom javascript for instances where Community Builder is not available to set this value.

Comment: You need to add a custom script tag to every page.